# react: осуществить переход между элементами-страницами

Tags: javascript, reactjs, архитектура, компоненты

Подскажите как более корректно сделать следующее (знаю несколько способов, но может это костыли и хотелось бы знать так ли это :))

есть независимые компоненты-страницы (т.е. занимают целую страницу и состоят из множества вспомогательных компонент) - `ComponentPage1`, `ComponentPage2`, `ComponentPage3`, `ComponentPage4`, ...

после того как пользователь заканчивает работу в одном компоненте, то переходит к следующему по нажатии на кнопку "Далее", следующий может получать данные от предыдущего или нет - это не существенно

**Как правильно реализовать такой переход?**

В голову приходит несколько способов:

1. через один из видов роутеров, например `HashRouter`

   ```
        <HashRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="page1/*" element={<ComponentPage1 />} />
                <Route path="page2/*" element={<ComponentPage2 />} />
                <Route path="page3/*" element={<ComponentPage3 />} />
                <Route path="page4/*" element={<ComponentPage4 />} />
            </Routes>
        </HashRouter>
   ```

а при нажатии просто переходить по соответствующей ссылке: `site#page2` и т.п.

Но для последовательного перехода от одной странице к следующей такой переход кажется кривоватым и избыточным (могу ошибаться)

2. через глобальную переменную идентификатора страницы (а за переменной следить уже средствами Mobx, Redux или подобным средством):

   ```
    const pages = {
      'page1': ComponentPage1, 
      'page2': ComponentPage2,
      'page3': ComponentPage3,
      'page4': ComponentPage4
    };

    ...

    {React.createElement(pages[global_page_id], params)}
   ```

Такой подход вроде как кажется правильным, но мало ли что

3. поскольку каждая следующая страница показывается только после предыдущей и никак иначе, то можно сделать такой подход - если в глобальную переменную идентификатора страницы идентификатор текущей страницы - отрисовываем её иначе отрисовываем следующую страницы - т.е. этакий рекурсивый подход

   ```
    {global_page_id === 'page2' ? this.CurrentContent() : <ComponentPage3 />}
   ```

Недостаток такого подхода - сам факт вложенности одного компонента в другой (не знаю насколько это правильно) и передача данных от 1 компонента к последнему через все остальные (хотя можно все хранить в одном глобальном месте)

**Подскажите какой же подход считается более правильным или вообще есть 4-ое решение, которое и надо использовать, а не творить костыли**

Comment: __Как правильно реализовать такой переход?__ 

Я вопрос не понял. Какой именно переход? Вы данные хотите отправить на следующую страницу или что?

Comment: не совсем, есть несколько совершенно разных страниц (т.е. нельзя сказать, что страница 1 является вариантом страницы 2), после действий на странице 1 пользователь (скажем по нажатию на кнопку "Далее") попадает на страницу 2 - вот и интересует вопрос, как это правильнее делать - в главном компоненте по некому состоянию отрисовывать соответствующий компонент или как-то еще